# О термине «уподобление» в литературе и грамматике

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, сравнительный-оборот, поэзия, анализ-текста

Заколдован невидимкой,

Дремлет лес под сказку сна.

Словно белою косынкой

Повязалася сосна.

```
            С. Есенин
```

Меня интересует два вопроса:

1. Как назвать оборот  «словно белою косынкой» **при анализе стихотворения?**

Какое это средство художественной выразительности? **Сравнение?** Но там нет двух сравниваемых предметов. **Метафора?**  Но там есть союз, скрытым сравнением уже не назовешь. Мне нравится термин **«уподобление»**, но его нет в перечне выразительных средств. Вероятно, уподобление – это  общая идея и для сравнения, и для метафоры.

2. Почему Розенталь  в правилах **все художественные сравнения называет уподоблением**, а общая тема у него называется «сравнительные обороты»?

Ведь сравнение в литературе  – это чисто **художественный прием** (впрочем, как и уподобление в целом), а у Розенталя в этой  теме рассмотрено  и **реальное отождествление (приравнивание),** которое по структуре ближе к теме обособленных приложений (а такие задачи решаются по своим правилам).

Все эти названия  без четкой классификации кажутся нелогичными  и  затрудняют анализ конструкции как при обособлении оборота, так и при художественном анализе.

Такая терминология была всегда и всех устраивала?  А как вы относитесь к таким названиям, вас что-нибудь затрудняет при их выборе? Можно ли предложить другую систематизацию и терминологию в этой теме?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133788/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------).

Comment: Запятая влияет на смысл. *Сосна повязалась, словно белою косынкой. Словно сосна повязалась белою косынкой.* Если без запятой, то лес сравнивается с сосной.

Comment: Ах, oleedd, не нужна здесь запятая.  Исходный вариант такой: Сосна словно повязалась белой косынкой.  Полный вариант метафоры: Верхушка сосны покрылась снегом, словно сосна повязалась белою косынкой.  В грамматике это сравнительное придаточное. Но у нас озвучено только придаточное, да еще с инверсией союза. Как назвать этот прием в литературе и в грамматике?

Comment: В таком случае "словно" плохо подходит, надо "будто".

Comment: Первое предложение самостоятельное, там точка стоит. Две совершенно разные мысли, два взгляда поэта: сначала на лес, потом на отдельные детали.

Comment: Чем принципиально словно отличается от будто?

Comment: "Будто" более удачно, когда присоединяем придаточное. Оно имеет более широкий охват.

Comment: А у нас и нет полного  сравнительного предложения, союзы же (будто, словно, точно)  я воспринимаю как очень близкие по значению синонимы.

Comment: Имел в виду: когда присоединяем придаточное к "будто". То есть включая придаточные без главного.

Comment: "Точно" сейчас редко используется, устаревает (полностью устаревает тогда, когда люди перестают понимать смысл, тогда из словарей убирают значение). "Будто" гораздо самостоятельнее. *Словно глядит сквозь матовое стекло.* Не хватает того, с чем сравнивается, как урывок мысли. *Будто глядит сквозь матовое стекло.* Так уже лучше звучит.

Comment: Лес, точно терем расписной,
Лиловый, золотой, багряный,
Веселой, пестрою стеной
Стоит над светлою поляной.  Будто (нейтр.), словно (будто поэт.), точно (в точности будто)

Comment: Что происходит в таких случаях? Сравнивается происходящее. Примеры: *Будто иду по Марсу. Словно вокруг поют птицы.* Больше характерно для разговорного стиля, обычно используется, когда собеседник знает о происходящем, чтобы передать свои впечатления.

Answer (score 1):

**ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ:**

Представим такую ситуацию: вы видели механического робота, который бежал, двигая задними лапами, как гепард; а также представим, что в этом мире нет гепардов, а вам нужно описать движение задними лапами  робота. Если бы вы знали, что ваш друг видел бег гепарда, то вы могли бы сказать, что робот бежал, как гепард, но так как ваш друг не видел гепарда, вам придётся тратить несколько предложений и, возможно, испытывать затруднения при описании этого движения. Вам придётся писать что-то вроде того, что робот оттягивает задние лапы намного ближе к передним, чем это делают другие животные, или что-то подобное. Но в данном случае с помощью общей лексики человек сможет дать какое-то представление об этом движении, но иногда описание просто невозможно.
Представим такую ситуацию: встречаются бывших два одноклассника и один другому говорит: ‟У девушки, которую я встретил, глаза как у Кати Ивановой [их бывшая одноклассница]”. Как бы он описал глаза, если бы они оба не видели Катю Иванову? Если они оба не знакомы с терминологией науки, вроде габитоскопии (наука в криминалистике для описания внешности), то никак. Похожий приём используется в песне Bette Davis Eyes, вот несколько строчек:

> И она будет дразнить вас
> Она будет смущать вас
> Всё лучше и лучше только чтобы понравиться вам
> Она рано созрела, и она знает
> Что требуется, чтобы сделать профессиональный румянец
> У нее отстранённый взгляд Греты Гарбо
> У нее глаза Бетт Дэвис

Я знаю, что здесь не сравнение, а метафора, так как глаза одной девушки называют глазами другой девушки, но тут вполне могло бы быть сравнение — глаза как у Бетт Дэвис; отстранённый взгляд как у Греты Гарбо.
Благодаря тому, что во время выхода песни Бетт Дэвис и Гретта Гарбо были известными актрисами, люди, слушая эту песню, могли понимать, о каком взгляде и о каких глазах идет речь.

В общем, если вам нужно сообщить определенные характеристики чего-то кому-то, то данный прием сравнения позволяет вам не пытаться сформулировать это — что может потребовать длительного времени, а иногда и может быть невозможным в нужной мере, — а просто указать на что-то, у чего ваш собеседник видел такие же характеристики. Вы просто пользуетесь явлением, которое заключается в совпадении параметров у разных предметов, процессов, действий, явлений.

**ВИДЫ СРАВНИТЕЛЬНЫХ ОБОРОТОВ:**

Я устал и больше не хочу писать этот ответ. В кратце.
На первый взгляд, я бы разделил на информативные — цель которых сообщить некую информацию (‟двигал лапами как гепард”, ‟глаза как у Кати Ивановой”, ‟Нильс был ростом как ложка”) и аффективные — цель которых создать впечатление, рассмешить, вызвать другую эмоцию и т.д. (‟План был прост, как деревенский толчёк”, ‟Её уста как роза”, ‟Степь покрылась как роем саранчи”).
Но всё, я устал. Меня хватило только на определение.
Может быть, потом допишу.

Comment: Можно было и мне дать сначала исправить собственные ошибки, но спасибо.

Comment: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=был+прост+как

Comment: Так вы ж устали, помогаю)

Comment: Только 2 исправил, всё не проверял.

Comment: Пожалуйста, развлекайтесь.

Comment: Не понял.......

Comment: Шутка, о том, что вы можете продолжать исправлять.

Comment: Вы согласны с запятой в "план был прост как деревенский толчёк"?

Comment: Я уже всё, очень устал и не хочу обсуждать что-либо. Как вы исправите, так пусть и будет.

Comment: Ещё пару исправил и тоже устал.

Comment: Смешные вы, ребята, а тема серьезная. У меня она подробно расписана, но систематизация материала изменена, да и терминология другая.  Хотелось бы хорошей критики с вашей стороны, но я не уверена, что у вас есть желание заниматься этим. Ладно, отложим пока...

Answer (score 1):

§ 42. Сравнительный оборот
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

**1. Систематизация материала у Розенталя**
(Я считаю, что изучить тему по этому материалу сложно.)

1. Сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся союзами будто, как будто, словно, нежели, чем, точно, что, выделяются запятыми, если…
2. Сравнительные обороты с союзами будто, как будто, словно, нежели, чем, точно, что не выделяются запятыми, если…
3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях: (1 – 5)  сравнительные обороты, указательные слова, союз как и, вводные слова, особые обороты).
4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми : (1 – 6) обстоятельство, отождествление, в качестве, часть сказуемого, частицы, фразеологизмы).

В конце неизвестный пункт 2 (примеры фразеологизмов)

**2. Какие недостатки я вижу**

(1) Отдельно разбираются два вида союзов, как будто это основной критерий, в  то время как решение задач для них имеет много общего.

(2) Не выделено в отдельную тему отождествление (приравнивание) – эта тема к сравнению вообще не относится, но в определенной степени касается обособления приложений.

(3) Основные варианты,  которые касаются различения обособленных и необособленных вариантов, перемешаны с частными темами (особые конструкции, вводные слова, фразеологизмы) .

(4) Нечеткая терминология (уподобление, сравнение), отличная от терминологии в литературе.

(5) Не рассмотрено отличие сравнительных оборотов от неполных сравнительных предложений.

**3. А какие недостатки видите вы?** Что вас затрудняет при изучении темы?
Помогите разобраться, пжста, для меня это важно.

Comment: Самое время вам переиздать Розенталя.

Comment: Для этого мой вариант должен быть лучше, чем у Розенталя, но не вносить никаких принципиальных изменений.  Все должно быть в пределах закона.  Мне нужна конструктивная критика. Даже наш вчерашний разговор уже дает материал для некоторых изменений в тексте, а еси вы серьезно к этому подойдете, может, половину переписывать придется.

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, что нужно делать)

Comment: Согласны с моей критикой, можете от себя что-то добавить?

Comment: Я согласен с критикой этой главы. Я не согласен лишь в мягких оценках её недостатков. На мой взгляд, это худшая глава в истории обучающей литературы. Я не думаю, что Розенталь сам понимал разницу между терминами ‟уподобление”, ‟отождествление”, ‟приравнивание”. Я думаю, что многое из этой главы вообще не имеет смысла, как, например, эти предложения про ‟он мне как брат” — если кто-то вам брат по крови, то не говорят ‟Он мне как брат”, а говорят ‟Он мне брат”.

Comment: (1) Какие два вида? Всегда указывайте. (2) Оно там оказалось лишь потому, что речь об оборотах с "как". Если в другую тему вставить, то вообще могут лишь что-то одно усвоить (либо что запятая нужна, либо что не нужна), ведь люди не читают все темы подряд. Вообще не вариант. Но про связь с приложениями согласен. (3) Добавьте примеры с вводными словами и особыми конструкциями. (5) Добавьте примеры. И это претензии не к Розенталю, а к тому, кто переделывал. Смотрите, как в оригинале: https://i.imgur.com/0tunjG2.png

Comment: А что вы понимаете под термином отождествление, чем он отличается от обычного сравнения?

Comment: @JimKorbett Отождествление — это когда кто-то является кем-то. А вот "уподобление" и "сравнение" вроде бы одно и то же.

Comment: @oleedd Я предлагаю вам, чтобы я написал формализацию данной темы, а вы нашли в ней прорехи; тогда можно будет обсуждать конкретные примеры и правила. Отождествление — это в качестве оборот?

Comment: @JimKorbett Пусть Sharon найдёт. У вас одна цель (расставить всё по полочкам и обобщить). Мне же достаточно того, что это всё понимаю. Ну да, когда "в качестве". Но там ещё есть примеры, в которых подставляется "считая" (по рекомендации Розенталя), то вроде бы приравнивание.